# Javascript AES in ECB mode with Pkcs5 padding

Tags: javascript, aes, ecb, pkcs#5

Is it possible in javascript to use AES in ECB mode with the Pkcs5 padding scheme?

The reason why i want to use the ECB mode is because it is desired by the client.

Comment: AFAIR JavaScript does not include any AES functionality by default, therefore if you can use AES/ECB/PKCS5 depends on the JavaScript cryptography library you use.

Comment: I've already searched the web for encryption libraries, but I didn't find one that supports this combination. To be honest i don't know much about encryption, so any information would be helpful.

Comment: @user1987623 I am looking for exactly same thing have you found anything on this?

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js looks like it has AES, ECB mode, and PKCS5 padding.

See http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/branches/3.x/src/cipher-core.js line 369, and http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/branches/3.x/src/mode-ecb.js.

Disclaimer: I know absolutely nothing about how well tested, audited, or maintained this library is, so you should do your own research on it before using it for anything important.

Comment: Note that PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, so do not worry about not seeing "PKCS#5" in crypto-js.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on "PKCS#5 being identical to PKCS#7". I've already explored the CryptoJS Library but I didn't see the PKCS#5 padding scheme anywhere.

Comment: Officially you cannot use PKCS#5 because it has only been specified for 8 byte block ciphers. But in practice they are identical.